# Trying to read text file and count words within defined groups

Tags: python, csv, text, sentiment-analysis

I'm a novice Python user. I'm trying to create a program that reads a text file and searches that text for certain words that are grouped (that I predefine by reading from csv). For example, if I wanted to create my own definition for "positive" containing the words "excited", "happy", and "optimistic", the csv would contain those terms. I know the below is messy - the txt file I am reading from contains 7 occurrences of the three "positive" tester words I read from the csv, yet the results print out to be 25. I think it's returning character count, not word count. Code:

```
import csv
import string
import re
from collections import Counter

remove = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n' + string.punctuation))

# Read the .txt file to analyze.
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    textanalysis = f.read()
    textresult = textanalysis.lower().translate(remove).split()

# Read the CSV list of terms.
with open("positivetest.csv", "r") as senti_file:
    reader = csv.reader(senti_file)
    positivelist = list(reader)

# Convert term list into flat chain.
from itertools import chain
newposlist = list(chain.from_iterable(positivelist))

# Convert chain list into string.
posstring = ' '.join(str(e) for e in newposlist)
posstring2 = posstring.split(' ')
posstring3 = ', '.join('"{}"'.format(word) for word in posstring2)

# Count number of words as defined in list category
def positive(str):
  counts = dict()

  for word in posstring3:
    if word in counts:
      counts[word] += 1
    else:
      counts[word] = 1

  total = sum (counts.values())
  return total


# Print result; will write to CSV eventually
print ("Positive: ", positive(textresult))
```

Comment: Some sample text would probably be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner as well but I stumbled upon a process that might help. After you read in the file, split the text at every space, tab, and newline. In your case, I would keep all the words lowercase and include punctuation in your split call. Save this as an array and then parse it with some sort of loop to get the number of instances of each 'positive,' or other, word.

Look at this, specifically the "train" function:

https://github.com/G3Kappa/Adjustable-Markov-Chains/blob/master/markovchain.py

Also, this link, ignore the JSON stuff at the beginning, the article talks about sentiment analysis:

https://dev.to/rodolfoferro/sentiment-analysis-on-trumpss-tweets-using-python-

Same applies with this link:

http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and passed through some of my own as a sample.
I have 2 idea's for you, based on what I think you may want.

First Assumption: You want a basic sentiment count?
Getting to 'textresult' is great. Then you did the same with the 'positive lexicon'  - to [positivelist] which I thought would be the perfect action? Then you converted [positivelist] to essentially a big sentence.
Would you not just:
1. Pass a 'stop_words' list through [textresult]
2. merge the two dataframes [textresult (less stopwords) and positivelist] for common words - as in an 'inner join'
3. Then basically do your term frequency
4. It is much easier to aggregate the score then

Second assumption: you are focusing on "excited", "happy", and "optimistic"
and you are trying to isolate text themes into those 3 categories?
1. again stop at [textresult]
2. download the 'nrc' and/or 'syuzhet' emotional valence dictionaries
       They breakdown emotive words by 8 emotional groups
       So if you only want 3 of the 8 emotive groups (subset)
3. Process it like you did to get [positivelist]
4. do another join

Sorry, this is a bit hashed up, but if I was anywhere near what you were thinking let me know and we can make contact. 
Second apology, Im also a novice python user, I am adapting what I use in R to python in the above (its not subtle either :) )

Comment: Thanks! Basically, I am trying to create my own customizable sentiment categories. So, i don't really care about those three words (excited, happy, optimistic) - those are just examples of what would make up a category. For example, if i want to define what it means to be positive, i might include those words plus others in a list to make a group. Then I want to compare text with that group and count how many matches the text has to any of the words in that group.